# How to resolve run time error in summary page? (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a feedback summary page. 
Here is the coding for the "send feedback button":

```
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("feedbacksummary.aspx");
}
```

The feedbacksummary page displays all the information the user has keyed in. In the page_load of the feedbacksummary page, here is the coding:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder contentHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            if (contentHolder != null)
            {
                TextBox txtComment = (TextBox)contentHolder.FindControl("txtMessage");
                TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)contentHolder.FindControl("txtEmail");
                TextBox txtFullName = (TextBox)contentHolder.FindControl("txtFullName");
                DropDownList rating = (DropDownList)contentHolder.FindControl("DropDownList1");
                TextBox txtSubject = (TextBox)contentHolder.FindControl("txtSubject");

                lblEmail.Text = txtEmail.Text;
                 lblFullName.Text = txtFullName.Text;
                 lblRating.Text = rating.Text;
               lblSubject.Text = txtSubject.Text;
                lblMessage.Text = txtComment.Text;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblEmail.Text= null;
            lblFullName.Text = null;
            lblRating.Text = null;
            lblSubject.Text = null;
            lblMessage.Text = null;
            lblwarning.Text = ex.Message;


        }
    }
```

The problem lies with the "confirm message" button in this page:

```
  protected void btnConfirmMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        string comment = lblMessage.Text;
        string email = lblEmail.Text;
        string rate = lblRating.Text;
        string name = lblFullName.Text;
        string subject = lblSubject.Text;

        UserFeedback fb = new UserFeedback(name, email, subject, rate, comment);
        FeedbackManager.GetInstance().AddFeedback(fb);
        Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");      
}
```

Instead of redirecting the user to welcome.aspx, it instead sends me back to feedbacksummary.aspx, but without any information displayed. This is how it looks like upon clicking the "confirm message button".

[image: Error screenshot]

How do code in such a way that upon clicking the "confirm message" button, it redirects me to welcome.aspx?

Comment: Have you debugged your code?  Set a break-point in the first lin in the btnConfirmMessage_Click method and click Confirm.  I'm pretty sure that your code is crashing somewhere before you reach the Redirect statement.  Some of your labels may be NULL or perhaps the FeedbackManager or the GetInstance() method on it are returning NULL.

Comment: Can you change ex.Message to ex.ToString() and share the output? I suspect PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent") returns null. Can you also share the HTML markup ?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at feedbacksummary.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user\Desktop\feedbacksummary.aspx.cs:line 18 (the entire error message). Line 18 in the cs file refers to: `ContentPlaceHolder contentHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent");`

Comment: As i wrote before, FindControl method is not able to return the MainContent control and casting to ContentPlaceholder fails. Can you please share the HTML markup so we can look in more detail?

Comment: Further to Ozan's comment you can do some fancy error catching with something like lblwarning.Text = ex.innerexception ?? ex.message.ToString()

Comment: Thanks! I initially used server.transfer from feedback to feedbacksummary. After using query string to transfer data the error was gone.